# Were the War Hammer Titan and the Cart Titan ever shown in the anime?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I've just watched the Attack on Titan anime series I havent read the manga. In the Attack on Titan wikia they mention the War Hammer Titan and the Cart Titan as part of the 9 titans. I've watched the whole one, two and three seasons of the anime, but I dont remember they been showed in them. Were the War Hammer Titan and the Cart Titan ever shown in the anime or they are supposed to appear later in the story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the Cart or War Hammer Titans have appeared by the point the anime has currently reached.

The most recent episode at time of writing is roughly equivalent to chapter 60 of the manga while the Cart Titan does not appear until chapter 75 and the War Hammer Titan in chapter 100.

Answer (score 0):

> The anime (currently season 3) is not up to the Return to Shiganshina Arc or Marley Arc, The Cart titan appears in C.74 (Part of RTS Arc), and the warhammer titan appears in Chapter 101 (Marley Arc).